# How to derive different maximum bending moments and sheer forces of a beam fixed at both ends?

Tags: structural-beam

I know how to derive the maximum bending moments and sheer forces of simply supported beams, but I'm having problems deriving these quantities of the beam fixed at both ends with an eccentric load.
https://www.awc.org/pdf/codes-standards/publications/design-aids/AWC-DA6-BeamFormulas-0710.pdf
In this link, **Fig. 25** the maximum sheer forces and two of the maximum bending moments are, $V_1$, $V_2$, $M1$, $M2$. 
$$R_1=V_1(max\ when\ a<b)=\frac{Pb^2}{l^3}(3a+b)$$
$$R_2=V_2(max\ when\ a>b)=\frac{Pa^2}{l^3}(a+3b)$$
$$M_1(max\ when\ a<b)=\frac{Pab^2}{l^2}$$
$$M_2(max\ when\ a>b)=\frac{Pa^2b}{l^2}$$
where $P$ is the load, $a$ and $b$ are distances of the point of load from two ends, respectively, and $l$ is the length of the beam.
**My question is how are these formulas derived?**
I know the derivations may be quite long. You could suggest some websites or videos in English that have explained these.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: See update with a specific link that should help you.

Answer (score 2):

The  problem is statically indeterminate because of the two fixed ends. You cannot use the static equilibrium equations alone to solve for the moments and reactions as you would for a simply supported beam. You need differential  equations for vertical deflection.

Google “fixed beam at both ends derivation” and you will find several derivations.

UPDATE: Found the following that gives a derivation. Specifically, look at example 10-4 in the link.

http://ocw.nthu.edu.tw/ocw/upload/8/259/Chapter_10-98.pdf

Hope this helps